# Running Chrome WebDriver on a linux server with no display

Tags: google-chrome, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, xvfb

I'd like to run automated tests using selenium2's chrome webdriver on a linux server.

I've already set up firefox to run on the server by using Xvfb (See http://www.semicomplete.com/blog/geekery/xvfb-firefox.html) and would like to do something similar with chrome. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, that should work just fine. What have you tried?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't been able to find a way to do this programmatically for the ChromeDriver like you can with the FirefoxBinary.

I've submitted a improvement request which has a patch attached to allow this. You can see it here: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2673

Edit:
You can see below response from Stephen on how to use this now the change has been merged.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16619608/998442

Comment: it appears your improvement request is marked as fixed. could you change your answer to explain how to use your fix?

Comment: Updated to add link to below response from Stephen showing how to set the display environment variable

Answer (score 26):

I was facing the same challenge of setting a linux box with selenium + chromedriver,
and here's my notes:

Pre-reqs:

1. Install JRE to run the selenium jar
2. Install the selenium server

   grab the jar file from https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list)
3. Install xvfb (you've seem to have already achieved this part)
4. Install google-chrome for your linux distribution
5. Download the chrome driver
   You can grab it from here: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads
6. Install other selenium dependencies that you might need (but the above is the minimum to get chromedriver to work)

To run:

1. Run xvfb

> `Xvfb :1 -screen 5 1024x768x8 &`
>
> `export DISPLAY=:1.5`

2. Run the selenium server jar with ChromeDriver options.
   It'll look something like this:

> `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.30.0.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.bin=/path/to/google-chrome -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/path/to/chromedriver`

3. The selenium server log should output something similar to this:

> Mar 19, 2013 10:07:27 AM org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher main
>   INFO: Launching a standalone server
>
> Setting system property webdriver.chrome.bin to {location of google-chrome}
>
> Setting system property webdriver.chrome.driver to {location of chromedriver}
>
> 10:07:34.258 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: `http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub`
>
> 10:07:34.259 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
>   10:07:34.259 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
>   ...

Reference: 
http://www.yann.com/en/use-xvfb-selenium-and-chrome-to-drive-a-web-browser-in-php-23/08/2012.html

Cheers!

Answer (score 11):

According to [SetEnvironmentProperty to ChromeDriver programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722615/setenvironmentproperty-to-chromedriver-programatically) you can do the following:

```
service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
    .usingChromeDriverExecutable(new File("/path/to/chromedriver"))
    .usingAnyFreePort()
    .withEnvironment(ImmutableMap.of("DISPLAY",":20"))
    .build();
```

Here is the [documentation for `withEnvironment`](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git-history/selenium-2.18.0/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeDriverService.Builder.html#withEnvironment%28java.util.Map%29)

Answer (score 0):

I get what you are trying to do, but you probably just run selenium grid. It was made for automated browser testing. Works great on a server.

https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/grid/