# SetEnvironmentProperty to ChromeDriver programmatically

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, xvfb

I am running tests with SE2 and firefoxDriver in a headless 
enviroment(Xvfb). With FirefoxDriver I can set the  DISPLAY environment property very 
easily:

```
     FirefoxBinary firefox = new FirefoxBinary(); 
     firefox.setEnvironmentProperty("DISPLAY",":"+DISPLAY); 
     FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new ProfilesIni().getProfile(Config.webDriverFirefoxProfile); 
     this.webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(firefox,firefoxProfile);
```

How can I do the above with ChromeDriver?

UPDATE: Seems that this is not possible to do yet! There is a similar question with mine here where explains the situation: [ChromeDriver Headless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023942/running-chrome-webdriver-on-a-linux-server-with-no-display)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

looks like they've fixed this (at least for now)

```
service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
        .usingChromeDriverExecutable(new File("/path/to/chromedriver"))
        .usingAnyFreePort()
        .withEnvironment(ImmutableMap.of("DISPLAY",":20"))
        .build();
```

Here's the revision in the code which adds this method:
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/detail?r=15232

Answer (score 1):

another non-programmatic approach, go to **/etc/chromium/default** (or **/etc/chromium-browser/default** or similar, depends on distribution) and set display there :

```
CHROMIUM_FLAGS="--display :99"
```