# Running Selenium tests with Chrome on Ubuntu in a headless environment

Tags: java, selenium

There's a massive amount of postings on this topic, but for some reason, I've found little relating to Chrome (it seems the support was recently added for headless). **The tests work running locally with a browser**.

1. Is it possible to trigger an Xvfb display from Java so I can manage everything in one place? I'd rather not have to do:

   Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1024x768x24 &

Via the command line. It'd be useful to run a display, then shut it down.

1. [SetEnvironmentProperty to ChromeDriver programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722615/setenvironmentproperty-to-chromedriver-programatically) is what I found to be the solution.

The problem? I can't get it to work on an Ubuntu machine.

The error I receive is:

```
/home/ubuntu/myproject/conf/chromedriver: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

The test class I'm using:

```
import java.io.File;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService;

import play.Logger;
import utils.LocalInfo;

import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;

public class TestCI {

    private WebDriver driver;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public TestCI(String url) {

        if (!LocalInfo.isEC2()) {

            Logger.info("Running tests by opening a browser...");

            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "conf/chromedriver");

            setWebDriver(new ChromeDriver());

        } else {

            Logger.info("Running tests headlessly...");

            String xPort = System.getProperty("Importal.xvfb.id", ":1");

            ChromeDriverService service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
                    .usingChromeDriverExecutable(new File("conf/chromedriver"))
                    .usingAnyFreePort()
                    .withEnvironment(ImmutableMap.of("DISPLAY", xPort)).build();

            setWebDriver(new ChromeDriver(service));

        }

        getWebDriver().get("http://www.google.com");

        try {
            someUITest();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        getWebDriver().close();

    }

    public WebDriver getWebDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    public void setWebDriver(ChromeDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void someUITest() throws Exception {

        getWebDriver().findElement(By.name("q"));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I switched to the chromedriver for linux and it got rid of the unterminated quoted string error http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list