# Configuring Xvfb to work with chromedriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, intern, xvfb

I'm using The Intern framework to run my Selenium tests. Now I want to run my tests with Google Chrome (chromedriver), but it requires virtual display to be configured. I'm thinking of using Xvfb for this. But I cant make the chromedriver to see that Xvfb is up and running for it.

If I run Xvfb and then run google-chrome browser, then everything is ok and browser sees Xvfb and use it. But if I run my test with chromedriver, I get an error "Display cant be open", so I make a conclusion that chromedriver does not see Xvfb.

Can anyone please help me to configure Xvfb to make chromedriver see it and use it?

Updated:
The question is not the same as here: [Running Chrome WebDriver on a linux server with no display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023942/running-chrome-webdriver-on-a-linux-server-with-no-display).
Because I need to setup display using the parameters when running chromedriver via SSH, eaither using some The Intern (framework) functionality (I dont know if it is supported at all). It's not about the pure selenium like in that question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Chrome WebDriver on a linux server with no display](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023942/running-chrome-webdriver-on-a-linux-server-with-no-display)

Answer (score 2):

I've figured out the problem.

The display can be configured by the following commands:
DISPLAY=:99.0
export DISPLAY

But I used this commands in another terminal windows, so they did not work. This commands should be typed in the same terminal window where chromedriver is runing.